# How do I interpret NVIDIA SMI output showing Fan Speed of more than 100%

Tags: gpu, nvidia, nvidia-smi

I have been working with historical NVIDIA SMI outputs for a while. I haven't really seen a Fan Speed of more than 100% in value. But in a new dataset I am working with, I am seeing a few readings that are above 100%. How do I interpret this?

From [the official documentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf):

> The fan speed value is the percent of maximum speed that the device's fan is currently intended to run at. It ranges from 0 to 100%. Note: The reported speed is the intended fan speed. If the fan is physically blocked and unable to spin, this output will not match the actual fan speed. Many parts do not report fan speeds because they rely on cooling via fans in the surrounding enclosure. For all discrete products with dedicated fans.

Despite that, I am seeing the following in my readings that were collected sometime between Sept 2021 and Oct 2021.

```
Mon Sep 27 04:10:01 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   22C    P8     7W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   23C    P8     7W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 49%   73C    P2   101W / 180W |   1053MiB /  8119MiB |     89%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 55%   81C    P2    62W / 180W |   1063MiB /  8119MiB |     84%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   25C    P8     6W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:85:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|635%   82C    P2   158W / 180W |    347MiB /  8119MiB |     84%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:88:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   19C    P8     7W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:89:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 47%   70C    P2   103W / 180W |    293MiB /  8119MiB |     76%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+




Sat Oct  9 09:00:02 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 40%   63C    P2   130W / 180W |    237MiB /  8119MiB |     76%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 47%   82C    P2   151W / 180W |    253MiB /  8119MiB |     79%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 49%   75C    P2   120W / 180W |    241MiB /  8119MiB |     76%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 54%   82C    P2   146W / 180W |    253MiB /  8119MiB |     78%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 49%   72C    P2   108W / 180W |    259MiB /  8119MiB |     77%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:85:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|541%   82C    P2   155W / 180W |    253MiB /  8119MiB |     79%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:88:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 48%   70C    P2   161W / 180W |    965MiB /  8119MiB |     86%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:89:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 47%   72C    P2   118W / 180W |    289MiB /  8119MiB |     78%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+


Wed Sep 22 20:20:01 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 48%   73C    P2   167W / 180W |    955MiB /  8119MiB |     87%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 53%   81C    P2   166W / 180W |    959MiB /  8119MiB |     89%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 52%   78C    P2   156W / 180W |    955MiB /  8119MiB |     88%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 54%   82C    P2   160W / 180W |    955MiB /  8119MiB |     90%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 43%   69C    P2   154W / 180W |    263MiB /  8119MiB |     82%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:85:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|739%   76C    P2   165W / 180W |    263MiB /  8119MiB |     85%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:88:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 42%   67C    P2   172W / 180W |    263MiB /  8119MiB |     84%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:89:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 46%   73C    P2   166W / 180W |    263MiB /  8119MiB |     87%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Also, this usually occurs on GPU index 5 of a particular host, what can one hypothesize from that?

Comment: My bet would be on "driver bug" as a theory :) Either by converting the data or by having some control loop computing nonsense for some inputs.

Comment: Given that there are multiple GTX1080 in the system, only one of which shows a non-sensical fan-speed value, a driver bug seems unlikely. If the problem isn't transient, I would suspect a sensor failure, or a problem with the I2C controller that handles the sensor data.

Comment: @njuffa Thank you, that seems a more reasonable hypothesis.